# Javascript to update textbox on ticking checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

How do we update a textbox on ticking checkboxes? Please see the following code, only 'School' gets filled on clicking the checkboxes. I would like to fill all the three words on ticking.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatebox()
{
    var textbox = document.getElementById("list")
    textbox.value =  ""

    if(document.getElementById('cb2').checked) {
        textbox.value = "School"
    }

    if(document.getElementById('cb3').checked) {
            textbox.value =  textbox.value + " College "
        }

    if(document.getElementById('cb4').checked) {
            textbox.value =  textbox.value + " University"
        }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="cb2" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="School" onclick="updatebox()" /> School <br />
<input id="cb3 "type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="College" onclick="updatebox()" /> College<br />
<input id="cb4" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="University" onclick="updatebox()" /> University<br />
<input id="list" type="text" name="list" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script is [throwing an error](http://jsbin.com/acored) because you don't have a checkbox called `"cb3"` (because of a typo in your HTML, it's either called `"cb3 "` -- with the space at the end -- or it doesn't have an ID at all [as [spaces are not valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) in IDs], depending on the browser). Without the typo, it [mostly works as you intended](http://jsbin.com/acored/2) although if School isn't checked, you get a space at the beginning and if University isn't checked but College is, you get a space at the end.

---

Side note #1: Your code is relying on the horror that is [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9). I strongly recommend **not** relying on it. Always include all required semicolons.

Side note #2: There are lots of ways to avoid having the space if "School" isn't ticked. One of the easiest is just to use an array and [`Array#join`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.5) with space as the separator, like this (I've also added the semicolons):

```
function updatebox()
{
    var textbox = document.getElementById("list");
    var values = [];

    if(document.getElementById('cb2').checked) {
        values.push("School");
    }

    if(document.getElementById('cb3').checked) {
        values.push("College");
    }

    if(document.getElementById('cb4').checked) {
        values.push("University");
    }

    textbox.value = values.join(" ");
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/acored/3) | [source](http://jsbin.com/acored/3/edit)

Side note #3: [`label` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) can make checkboxes much easier to use by allowing clicking on the label as well as the actual box:

```
<label><input id="cb2" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="School" onclick="updatebox()" /> School</label><br />
<label><input id="cb3" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="College" onclick="updatebox()" /> College</label><br />
<label><input id="cb4" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="University" onclick="updatebox()" /> University</label><br />
<input id="list" type="text" name="list" />
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/acored/4) | [source](http://jsbin.com/acored/4/edit)

Answer (score 3):

You've got a typo on the line where you define cb3:

```
<input id="cb3 "type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="College" onclick="updatebox()" /> College<br />
```

should be

```
<input id="cb3" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="College" onclick="updatebox()" /> College<br />
```

Also you should use semi-colons to finish your Javascript statements.

Corrected code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatebox()
{
    var textbox = document.getElementById("list");
    textbox.value = "";

    if(document.getElementById('cb2').checked) {
        textbox.value = "School";
    }

    if(document.getElementById('cb3').checked) {
            textbox.value =  textbox.value + " College ";
        }

    if(document.getElementById('cb4').checked) {
            textbox.value =  textbox.value + " University";
        }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="cb2" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="School" onclick="updatebox()" /> School <br />
<input id="cb3" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="College" onclick="updatebox()" /> College<br />
<input id="cb4" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="University" onclick="updatebox()" /> University<br />
<input id="list" type="text" name="list" />

</body>
</html>
```